# change selected item color in custom Navigation bar on different screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have built custom navigation bar and displaying it on 3 different screens.As i select 2 and 3 screen, screen is navigating but icon at index 0 remains selected. Working fine when first screen is selected but not on other 2 screens.

here is code for custom navi bar:

```
class CustomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomNavigationBarState createState() => _CustomNavigationBarState();
  }

  class _CustomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomNavigationBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

double deviceWidth(BuildContext context) =>
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: deviceWidth(context) * 0.1),
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 25),
  height: screenHeight * 0.1,
  width: screenWidth * 0.6,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Constants.menu_color,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        blurRadius: 8,
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      buildNaviBarItem(Icons.home, 0, () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          HomeScreen.routeName,
        );
      }),
      buildNaviBarItem(Icons.search, 1, () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          SearchScreen.routeName,
        );
      }),
      buildNaviBarItem(Icons.favorite_border, 2, () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          FavoriteScreen.routeName,
        );
      }),
    ],
  ),
);
} Widget buildNaviBarItem(IconData icon, int index, Function onPressed) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      onPressed();
    });
  },
  child: Container(
    child: Icon(
      icon,
      color: index == _selectedIndex
          ? Colors.white
          : Constants.text_Color.withOpacity(0.6),
      size: 38,
    ),
  ),
);
}
 }
```

here how i displayed this navigation bar on all 3 screens:

```
extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar(),
```

[image: this is 2nd screen(search page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Your selected item color code works fine, but `Navigator.pushNamed` cause this issue, instead you can return `Screen` 
Step 1: pass `callback` get current index

```
class CustomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(int) callback;
...  
    Widget buildNaviBarItem(IconData icon, int index, Function onPressed) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
              onPressed();
              widget.callback(index);
            });
          },
```

Step 2: return `Screen` with `currentIndex`

```
Widget _switch(currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      print("Home");
      return HomeScreen();
    } else if (currentIndex == 1) {
      print("Search");
      return SearchScreen();
    } else {
      print("Favorite");
      return FavoriteScreen();
    }
  }

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: _switch(currentIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar(callback: (val) {
        setState(() {
          print(val);
          currentIndex = val;
        });
      }),
```

working demo

[image]

working demo 2

[image]

full code 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(int) callback;

  CustomNavigationBar({this.callback});
  @override
  _CustomNavigationBarState createState() => _CustomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomNavigationBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    double deviceWidth(BuildContext context) =>
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: deviceWidth(context) * 0.1),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 25),
      height: screenHeight * 0.1,
      width: screenWidth * 0.6,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //color: Constants.menu_color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 8,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildNaviBarItem(Icons.home, 0, () {}),
          buildNaviBarItem(Icons.search, 1, () {}),
          buildNaviBarItem(Icons.favorite_border, 2, () {}),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildNaviBarItem(IconData icon, int index, Function onPressed) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
          onPressed();
          widget.callback(index);
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: index == _selectedIndex
              ? Colors.white
              : Colors.green.withOpacity(0.6),
          size: 38,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  Widget _switch(currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      print("Home");
      return HomeScreen();
    } else if (currentIndex == 1) {
      print("Search");
      return SearchScreen();
    } else {
      print("Favorite");
      return FavoriteScreen();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: _switch(currentIndex),
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar(callback: (val) {
        setState(() {
          print(val);
          currentIndex = val;
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2, //横轴三个子widget
            childAspectRatio: 1.0 //宽高比为1时，子widget
        ),
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
        ]);
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2, //横轴三个子widget
            childAspectRatio: 1.0 //宽高比为1时，子widget
        ),
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=12'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=13'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=14'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=15'),
          Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=16'),
        ]);
  }
}

class FavoriteScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Favorite");
  }
}
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(int) callback;

  CustomNavigationBar({this.callback});
  @override
  _CustomNavigationBarState createState() => _CustomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomNavigationBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    double deviceWidth(BuildContext context) =>
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: deviceWidth(context) * 0.1),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 25),
      height: screenHeight * 0.1,
      width: screenWidth * 0.6,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //color: Constants.menu_color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 8,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildNaviBarItem(Icons.home, 0, () {}),
          buildNaviBarItem(Icons.search, 1, () {}),
          buildNaviBarItem(Icons.favorite_border, 2, () {}),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildNaviBarItem(IconData icon, int index, Function onPressed) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
          onPressed();
          widget.callback(index);
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: index == _selectedIndex
              ? Colors.white
              : Colors.green.withOpacity(0.6),
          size: 38,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  Widget _switch(currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      print("Home");
      return HomeScreen();
    } else if (currentIndex == 1) {
      print("Search");
      return SearchScreen();
    } else {
      print("Favorite");
      return FavoriteScreen();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: _switch(currentIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar(callback: (val) {
        setState(() {
          print(val);
          currentIndex = val;
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Home");
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Search");
  }
}

class FavoriteScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Favorite");
  }
}
```

Comment: i got a problem due this navigation bar on all screens except homescreen. are u here ?

Comment: could you post reproduce code for this error? thanks.

Comment: i did the same as u said.. Problem is that extendedbody = true is working fine for homescreen but not for 2 other screens, I used Extended widget on listview but it is not taking full screen height due to navi bar.. attached screenshot of 2nd screen above.